# If $\frac {a}{3^{x-1}}=\frac{b}{3^{y+2}}=\frac{c}{3^{z-1}}=\frac 15\;$ then which of the following equals $a×b×c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, contest-math, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation

The problem is:

> If $\frac {a}{3^{x-1}}=\frac{b}{3^{y+2}}=\frac{c}{3^{z-1}}=\frac 15,\;$ then  which of the following equals $a×b×c$ ?
>
> A) $\frac {1}{375}$
>
> B)  $\frac{1}{125}$
>
> C)  $\frac{27}{125}$
>
> D)  $\frac{3}{125}$
>
> E)  $\frac{27}{5}$

I think the question is wrong.

My counterexample:

> Let $x=m,\; y=m-3,\; z=m.$
>
> Then $a=b=c=\frac{3^{m-1}}{5}.$
>
> So,  $a×b×c=\frac{3^{3m-3}}{125},\; m\in\mathbb{R}.$

Am I right?

Comment: "$a \times b \times c$ which of the following" maybe you need a verb for this sentence? :P

Comment: @L.F. Or maybe only an "is" ;P

Comment: @ary Technically "is" is also a verb XD

Answer (score 2):

Yes some information is missing, indeed we have that

$$\frac {a}{3^{x-1}}=\frac{b}{3^{y+2}}=\frac{c}{3^{z-1}}=\frac 15$$

then

$$abc=\frac{3^{(x+y+z)}}{125}$$

then we need a condition for $t=x+y+z\in \mathbb R$, since $3^{t}$ can assume any value  $\in(0,\infty)$.